# Timestamp as " X Days Ago", can't modify script correctly

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a todo list app I'm working on. It displays the timestamp from when a todo was created and even allows the user to choose what the format should be.

In this snippet, the code grabs info from a mySQL db to see how to format the date:

```
public function __toString(){
    // The string we return is outputted by the echo statement

    if ( $this->data['date_created'] == '') {
        $date_created =  date($GLOBALS["config"]["date_format"].' '.$GLOBALS["config"]["time_format"]);
    }
    else 
        $date_created = date($GLOBALS["config"]["date_format"].' '.$GLOBALS["config"]["time_format"], strtotime($this->data['date_created']));
```

(It's pulling from a row called date_format and a row called time_format)

I'm trying to implement this code:

```
function relativeTime($dt,$precision=2) {
    if(is_string($dt)) $dt = strtotime($dt);

    $times=array(   365*24*60*60    => "year",
                    30*24*60*60     => "month",
                    7*24*60*60      => "week",
                    24*60*60        => "day",
                    60*60           => "hour",
                    60              => "minute",
                    1               => "second");

    $passed=time()-$dt;

    if($passed<5)
    {
        $output='less than 5 seconds ago';
    }
    else
    {
        $output=array();
        $exit=0;

        foreach($times as $period=>$name)
        {
            if($exit>=$precision || ($exit>0 && $period<60)) break;

            $result = floor($passed/$period);
            if($result>0)
            {
                $output[]=$result.' '.$name.($result==1?'':'s');
                $passed-=$result*$period;
                $exit++;
            }
            else if($exit>0) $exit++;
        }

        $output=implode(' and ',$output).' ago';
    }

    return $output;
}
```

I replaced `$dt` with `$date_created` and tried different combos, but I can't seem to get it right. I have a frontend error telling me that relativetime is undefined (it doesn't say relativeTime in error message, it has a lowercase "t"). What can I do to get `$date_created` to show up in the "Days ago" format? Thanks!

Comment: can you provide a piece of code where you're calling relativeTime function? isn't it incapsulated within some class by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite this completely as something like this:

```
$times = array(365*24*60*60    => "year",
               30*24*60*60     => "month",
               7*24*60*60      => "week",
               24*60*60        => "day",
               60*60           => "hour",
               60              => "minute",
               1               => "second");

$passed = time() - $dt;

if ($passed < 5) {
    echo "Less than 5 seconds ago.";
} else {
    foreach ($times as $period => $name) {
        if ($passed >= $period) {
            echo round($passed / $period) . " " . $name . "(s) ago";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

See this link for an example (I've hardcoded the value of `$passed` for testing purposes; you can edit the value to see how it affects things):

http://ideone.com/e8KXK

---

*As an aside, I've realized that I think your original solution attempts to fully account for every second that has passed.  This is a bad idea from a user experience perspective.  I don't think many users will want to see **"Created 1 year and 7 months and 19 days and 4 hours and 36 minutes and 28 seconds ago"**, which is the type of result that your original code was shooting for.  This answer will only display the largest unit.*

Comment: Thank you both so much for the responses! This is how I'm trying to call relativeTime:
`if ( $this->data['date_completed'] == '') {
$date_completed = '';
return '
<li id="Item-'.$this->data['id'].'" class="item">'
      .ToDo::showDate($GLOBALS["show_item_date"],$this->data).'
      <div class="text">'.$this->data['text'].'</div>
      <div class="description">'.$this->data['description'].'</div>
      <div class="date">'.relativeTime($row['date_created']).'</div>
      <div class="dateCreated">'.$date_created.'</div>
      <div class="dateCompleted">'.$date_completed.'</div>
     </li>';
  }`

Comment: Ok, now it just comes down to my lack of math skills. I changed your code so $passed = time() - $date_completed;

Then, I changed it so if ($passed >= $period) {
            $date_launched = ($passed / $period) . " " . $name . "(s) ago";
            break;

and the result is 42.5714872527 year(s) ago

Not sure what I did to mess up the equation?
        }

Comment: What is the value of `$date_completed`?  (Note that it is a decimal because you have removed the call to `round()`)

Comment: Thanks! Here is what I ended up with:
`$passed = time() - strtotime($this->data['date_created']);`
and I added round and it works. The only thing that doesn't work, which I think is a new question and not appropriate for this thread, is that when you first add a todo, the timestamp says "43 year(s) ago" and only after refreshing the page does it grab the right date. So I guess it's a matter of instantly doing a query on submit or something. Thank you everyone for their help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this functions for dates in the future or passed dates.

```
function relativeTime($dt,$precision=2) {
        if(is_string($dt)) $dt = strtotime($dt);
        $times = array(365*24*60*60    => "year",
                   30*24*60*60     => "month",
                   7*24*60*60      => "week",
                   24*60*60        => "day",
                   60*60           => "hour",
                   60              => "minute",
                   1               => "second");

        $passed = abs(time() - $dt);

        if ($passed < 5) {
            echo "Less than 5 seconds ago.";
        } else {
            foreach ($times as $period => $name) {
                if ($passed >= $period) {
                    $value = round($passed / $period);
                    $nameReal = $name;
                    if($value != 1) $nameReal .= "s";

                    if(time() > $dt)
                        echo  $value . " " . $nameReal . " ago";
                    else
                        echo "In ". $value . " " . $nameReal;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```